# pivotal cloud foundry (PCF) : spring cloud bus service id

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

I need to invoke the refresh and env endpoints for all instances (10+) of a Service.

Service is sourcing its env. from spring cloud config server and listening for updates using spring cloud bus.

Works fine when the instances are outside PCF(no profile): all instances have the same service id : {spring.application.name}

However when running in PCF (cloud profile): instances have different service id : the dynamic vcap.application.port is appended to the serviceId, making each instance(Id) unique.Thus each instance needs to be refreshed separately.

Any ideas on how to go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

This [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus/issues/17) was recently closed. Try a snapshot and use a wildcard for the identifier, e.g. `/bus/refresh?destination=customers:**`.